# multidimensional array with JavaScript just like php

Tags: javascript

How do I write multidimensional array with JavaScript just like php in where I can loop it and search it based on the key value.

```
        var domainme = array( 
                [0] array (
                        "domain" => "one.com",
                        "database" => "one",
                        "api" => "one.php"
                    )               
                [1] array (
                        "domain" => "two.com",
                        "database" => "two",
                        "api" => "two.php"
                    )               
                [2] array (
                        "domain" => "three.com",
                        "database" => "three",
                        "api" => "three.php"
                    )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript distinguishes between *arrays* and *objects* (although arrays are also objects). You'd write what you have like this:

```
var domainme = [
    {domain: "one.com", database: "one", api: "one.php"},
    {domain: "two.com", database: "two", api: "two.php"},
    {domain: "three.com", database: "three", api: "three.php"}
];
```

`[]` defines an array literal, `{}` defines an object literal.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an array of object.

Like :

```
var domainme = [{
  "domain": "one.com",
  "database": "one",
  "api": "one.php"
}, {
  "domain": "two.com",
  "database": "two",
  "api": "two.php"
}, {
  "domain": "three.com",
  "database": "three",
  "api": "three.php"
}]
```

To get a value you can do :

```
domainme[0]["domain"] // get : 'one.com'
//or 
domainme[0].domain // get : 'one.com'
```

Comment: `"domain" => "two.com"` is a syntax error in JavaScript.